# Funcion para que detecte un elemento en una div y si no consigue el elemento la funcion debe crear el elemento, Js o jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, div

Estoy trabajando con un codigo que no es mio, cuando realizo la siguiente funcion

```
function() {
  $('<div class="btnComprarHover"></div>')s.insertBefore(".product-name");
}
```

ella queda generando una y otra vez el elemento`<div class="btnComprarHover"></div>` asi que pense en hacer una funcion en la que detecte el elemento`<div class="btnComprarHover"></div>`y en caso que la respuesta sea true ella no lo genere, pero si la respuesta en false genere el elemento `<div class="btnComprarHover"></div>`

Comment: Hola y bienvenido. Por favor sé un poco más claro con tu pregunta, no está bien redactada. (Cómo preguntar https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Muéstranos la función que mencionas para detectar el elemento `btnComprarHover`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Con jQuery debes seleccionar el elemento y comprobar si el array resultante tiene elementos dentro. Si no tiene elementos entonces lo creas. Yo usaría un id en vez de una clase porque lo que entiendo es que solo va a existir un elemento btnComprarHover:

```
if($('#btnComprarHover').length == 0) {
    $('<div id="btnComprarHover"></div>').insertBefore(".product-name");
}
```

Comment: Utilizo class porque nesesito agregar un boton de comprar a todos los productos del catalogo, pero me fuinciono perfectamente, muchas gracias amigo